# php - Read json data from url and save to variable

Tags: php, json

I try to read json data from url in php and save it to a variable.

The json data:

```
 {"Temp1":[{"time":123,"value":178},{"time":123,"value":152},{"time":123,"value":193},{"time":123,"value":184},{"time":123,"value":198},{"time":123,"value":152}],"Temp2":[{"time":123,"value":161},{"time":123,"value":197},{"time":123,"value":183},{"time":123,"value":166},{"time":123,"value":194},{"time":123,"value":170}],"Temp3":[{"time":123,"value":157},{"time":123,"value":188},{"time":123,"value":167},{"time":123,"value":173},{"time":123,"value":175},{"time":123,"value":152}],"Temp4":[{"time":123,"value":159},{"time":123,"value":181},{"time":123,"value":157},{"time":123,"value":184},{"time":123,"value":195},{"time":123,"value":153}]}
```

In php i try to get the results with:

```
$url = 'https://  .... /getLastCycles'; 
$json_string = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($json_string);
```

But **var_dump($json)** returns only "NULL".

The Json is valid but **json_last_error** generates "JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX". In JavaScript **$.getJSON** works fine with the json data.

In php the data output is generated by:

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($jsondata, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

I tried also to get the data with curl. Trim, stripslashes and removing any spaces don´t work also.

Where is my mistake here?

Comment: is the `url` your own site or a remote site?

Comment: It is on the own (same) site

Comment: Does `$json_string` contain anything?

Comment: have you checked that you are getting valid json string here `$json_string = file_get_contents($url);`?

Comment: Yes var_dump return "string(24242)" and below the "mainpage/loginpage" is loaded 
. It seem that the gets_content get an http answer instead json ....

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue:
The controller of the url has access validation based on session:

```
 if (!$this->check_acl('View Tool')){
              redirect('noaccess');
            }
```

But why the browser request is accepted and the file_gets_content not is strange.

Thanks.